# How I could install NGINX from nginx.org repo using yum in CentOS-8?

Tags: nginx, centos, yum, rpm, centos8

Problem: After enabling repos, like I did for centos-7, yum just does not see any Nginx RPMs from nginx.org repo:

```
# cat << 'EOF' > /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
#baseurl=https://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
baseurl=https://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
gpgkey=http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
module_hotfixes=true
EOF

# yum -y update
# yum install nginx-1.18.0-2.el8.ngx
No package nginx-1.18.0-2.el8.ngx available.
```

Any plays with `yum module` just switch between default ones. But nginx.org is ignored under **ANY** conditions.

Comment: Which repo did you enable?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Stable and Mainline

Comment: Well that's odd, the packages are there. What is the problem you had?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  yum just does not see any Nginx RPMs from Nginx.org repo

Comment: *After enabling repos, like I did for centos-7* what does that consist of, exactly?

Comment: @Bert I have edited description

Comment: Have you ran `dnf install nginx`